# way to use data immediately when its return from HTTP request without waiting to loop throw all array element

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I had a for loop in ts that loop throw list and for each array element make an HTTP request to get its detail , but I always had an error that there is now detailed because this loop take a lot of time , 
so there is any way to use each detailed One after the other without waiting to loop throw all array ?
 ***i need to use detailed immediately when its return from HTTP***

```
this.allAnalysisData.forEach((analysis) => {
        this.analysisCenterService.getAnalysisDetails(analysis.id).subscribe(detail => {
            this.detailed.push({Analysis:analysis , det:detail});
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `async` operator to `await` result your API call:

```
async fooFunction() 
{
    this.allAnalysisData.forEach((analysis) => {
        let detail= await this.analysisCenterService.getAnalysisDetails(analysis.id);
        this.detailed.push({Analysis:analysis , det:detail});
    });
}
```

If return type of `getAnalysisDetails` is `Observable`, then you can convert to `Promise` using `.toPromise` method:

```
 let result = await this.analysisCenterService.getAnalysisDetails(analysis.id).toPromise();
```

**UPDATE:**

[As docs says about `.toPromise`:](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/topromise.md)

> Converts an Observable sequence to a ES2015 compliant promise.

Comment: yes return type of getAnalysisDetails is Observable but await not found in typescript

Comment: @omarasi just use `.toPromise()` method. Please, see the bottom part of my reply

Comment: can you tell me what .toPromise() do ?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be nested your subscriptions within a forEach loop, and vice versa. Instead, you should be making full use of RxJS operators, since RxJS is natively available in Angular.

For this instance, you can make use of [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html),

> When all observables complete, emit the last emitted value from each.

forkJoin() will wait for the `Array.forEach()` loop to be completed before returning all the observables.

```
const observableList = [];

this.allAnalysisData.forEach((analysis) => {
  observableList.push(this.analysisCenterService.getAnalysisDetails(analysis.id));
});

forkJoin(observablesList).subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response);
  // handle the rest
});
```

Comment: how your code will subscribe all observablesList ? there is no loop !

Comment: `observableList` contains the list of observables from looping of `allAnalysisData`, and the request to `getAnalysisDetails`

Comment: Have you tried my code? If you follow what I have done and subscribe to  `observablesList`, you will be able to get all of the returned responses

Comment: @wentjun forkJoin will wait for observable list to complete?

Comment: @AliWahab yes it will. It will wait for all observables to complete, before returning the values. This way it won't be undefined

Comment: Its a good solution but I was thinking that if I have 10 requests. So it will wait to execute those 10 request and then start returning values. Which will take good time to execute

Comment: @AliWahab If you want it to start returning values when any of the request has been returned (without waiting for all request to be returned), you can use `combineLatest` instead of `forkJoin`

Comment: i  tried your code exactly but it does not arrive to console statement !! are you sure that forkJoin can use in typescript

Comment: @omarasi yes, it works 100% with Angular and TypeScript. Have you tried using combineLatest then

Comment: @omarasi make sure you're importing forkJoin from rxjs

Comment: both combineLatest & forkJoin wait for all observableList to subscribe , i want to return subscribed element immediately

Answer (score 0):

you can use like
return forkJoin(
     this.allAnalysisData.map(analysis=> this._httpClient.get('url of services'+ analysis))
 ).subscribes(response=> {});